# I am changing Emirates flight at Dubai for an onward flight to Geneva .Do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas

I am an Indian Doctor. I am flying to Geneva on Emirates.  Only changing flights at Dubai. Gap of  2 hrs. Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: BTW the flight from Mumbai -> Geneve is very nice!  But the flight backwards has much better food!

Answer (score 4):

**No, you do not**.
Source: Timatic, the "bible of Airlines" https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=AE&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=tw&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C

> Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

Dubai has a transit area, meaning you won't deal with any immigration officers. In such cases (of airside transit), it's all about whether the airline lets you board, and they go by Timatic